# Phone temperature sensor not working - Charging slow - How to fix?

Tags: root-access, charging, sensors, edxposed

Recently, something has happened to my phone's temperature sensor. It's showing ridiculously high values for the temperature (over 100 degrees), even though it's very cold. This has caused my phone to refuse fast charging, and it charges very, very slowly. (~7 hours to charge)

Is there anyway I could turn off a sensor or fake its value so that my phone charging returns to normal?

Or is there anyway to force the phone to ignore the thermal limits during charging? (I know it's dangerous but I have no choice)

Deleting the thermal engine file doesn't fix the issue.

P.S: Android 10 | Qualcomm chipset | Rooted + Xposed

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned anywhere that you have root access but since you've added aa root-access tag i'm assuming you have root access.

[Sensor disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrchandler.disableprox&hl=en&gl=US) is what you are searching for. Just be careful!

P.S.: Take a look at this too https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-maxx/help/how-to-disable-temp-sensor-t3504585

Generally in all phones temperature is the battery temperature and as far as i have read in many threads this is rare and indicates terrible hardware issue. And there is no way to change the value. There must be a way to bypass the temperature check though. I'd recommend you to go to a shop and get it diagnosed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes I have root access.
The app you mentioned doesn't have any options for the temperature sensor.

Comment: Generally in all phones temperature is the battery temperature and as far as i have read in many threads this is rare and indicates terrible hardware issue. And there is no way to change the value. There must be a way to bypass the temperature check though. I'd recommend you to go to a shop and get it diagnosed. Comment when you see this. I'll delete my answer

Comment: Thanks. No need to delete it. It might help someone else with a sensor problem.
Of course my #1 thought was to get it repaired, but I couldn't find any official support center for that brand in my country.